# Set a property in a style sheet to the value of another property?

Tags: qt, qt4

I would like to set the "!active" background-color of QTableWidget to match the "active" color. I tried to do this:

```
QTableWidget::item:selected:!active{
background-color:QTableWidget::item:selected:active;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to set a property's value to the value of another property?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing other styles from within a style is not possible.  I can think of two alternatives:

1) Modify the QPalette of your QTableWidget from within your code. The QPalette object will give you access to the properties you're looking for.

```
QPalette palette = myTableWidget->palette();
palette.setColor( QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Highlight, palette.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Highlight) );
palette.setColor( QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::HighlightedText, palette.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::HighlightedText) );
myTableWidget->setPalette( palette );
```

2) Use some QString magic:

```
 QString styleSheet = QString( "QTableWidget::item:selected:active { %1 }"
                               "QTableWidget::item:selected:!active { %1 }" )
                               .arg( "style_for_both_items" )
```

Comment: Hm, I guess the problem is that I don't know the value of item:selected:active's background-color, so I don't know how to set !active to the same color. I looked at the QPalette doc and am not sure how I would get this value? Also, I'd like to set this through the QtDesigner if possible - but I'll take a programmatic solution at this point :)

Comment: I thought this would do it, but it doesn't work - the inactive selected color is still gray, while the active one is orange. (I would have expected them both to be orange).

http://pastebin.com/uvSC2rPU

Comment: I guess in the same spirit as your answer to my last question, I should be setting the property of tableWidget->currentItem()->palette() rather than the tableWidget directly... but this time I'd have to handle a signal to set this because currentItem is not defined until I click something. Is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: I updated my QPalette answer to be more specific on which palette elements to modify. I'm fairly certain there's no way to do this from within designer, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Hm, even after setting QPalette::Highlight and QPalette::HighlightedText as you suggest, the row still turns gray when the table loses focus?

Comment: I just tested this with a minimal program and the palette method seems to work fine.  However, it should be noted that if you're using style sheets to mess with the cell colors as well, they are likely going to interfere with each other.

Comment: Hm I don't have any style sheet stuff set. Here is my minimial example: daviddoria.com/Uploads/TableWidgetSelectRow.zip - I would expect the selected row in the left table to stay orange even when I select a row of the right table, but it does not.

Comment: Someone suggested I try running my program with: -style Cleanlooks . When I do this, it indeed works properly! Any idea why it wouldn't work the same way with a default theme? (I am on Ubuntu 11.10 and using gnome fallback)

Comment: kdepepo on IRC mentioned "the gtk_paint_flat_box() call draws the color, so if you are using the GTK engine, it does not use Qt colors, but GTK colors. the GTK engine creates a fake widget, but never transfers the option.palette onto it afterwards, so it always uses the same colors. and the cache is not per-widget either, so it looks like a design choice."

Comment: I guess Qt is just not really cross platform in some aspects when it comes to style related things. That is unfortunate :(